# Entity framework CF, проблема с DatabaseGenerated

Tags: entity-framework

После миграции БД, EF отказывается работать с таблицей, где установлен DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity (по умолчанию). После установки DatabaseGeneratedOption.None все заработало, но при добавлении ключевое поле не прибавляется автоматически. Т.Е. ID всегда становится равен 0. Как это решить?

Answer (score 1):

Объясните подробнее что значит отказывается работать?

Насколько я понимаю, свойство DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity говорит EF-у что на стороне базы данных существует ограничение по умолчанию (default constraint) на поле, а посему необходимо не включать это поле в запрос на insert а после успешной вставки подгрузить содержимое этого поля из БД в сущность в контексте.
Если это свойство убрать то каждый раз при вставке EF будет генерировать запрос вида

`insert into table table1 (ID, Value, Comment) values ('0', '123', 'test')`

нежели

`insert into table table1 (Value, Comment) values ('123', 'test')`

возможно при миграции у вас пропало ограничение по умолчанию на поле, поэтому теперь DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity не работает